# Eclipse + SVN: Opening edited/selected file in version from base revision?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

Is there any quick way to open currently edited / selected file without local modifications (i.e. in version in base revision from SVN). Currently I do it this way: I go to history of that file and open version from base revision. But it's so common operation for me that I would like to do it in one step (or even using hotkey!).

Note I don't mean comparing current version of file with base version which is pretty simple but compare editor is often too verbose for my needs and what's more important it doesn't support features of normal Java editor like jumping to selected method/class etc.

I'm using Subclipse but I'm also interested in Subversive answer if it doesn't exist for Subclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage Subclipse.

All Subclipse operations should be available to setup as key bindings, but there is not operation in the UI to do this so you could not bind a key either.  I am not really clear what you want to do and more importantly why.  I am not aware of any SVN client that can open the base version of a file other than the via the diff option.

Have you tried enabling the Quick Diff feature and configuring it to use the SVN pristine copy as the base?  This lets you use your normal editor and then it annotates all the areas of the file with modifications and you can get a quick hover to see what the previous version was.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the Team Provider (Subclipse or Subversive) to provide a command that does this. I could not find one in Subclipse, but I don't know about Subversive. To find out if there is a command for this, you can do it either:

1. `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys` and search for svn (or other things)
2. `Window -> Customized Perspective` this will give you a dialog that has tabs where you can find all of the commands that are available. Look in the `SVN` sections.